# Printing char to file gives weird result

Tags: c, file, io, char, file-writing

So I am printing char's to a file and whenever the line ends it just does something weird.

This is the code I use:

```
void opdracht43() {
    FILE *file;
    FILE *file2;
    file = fopen("opdracht1.1.cpp", "r");
    file2 = fopen("Disc.c", "w");
    int p;
    char a[100];
    while (fgets(a, 100, file)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof a; i++) {
            if (a[i] == '\n' || a[i] == ' ' || a[i] == '\t') {
                printf("TRUE");
            }
            else {
                printf("FALSE");
                fputc(a[i], file2);
            }
        }
        return 0; //So it only prints the 1st line for now.
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(file2);
}
```

And when this runs this is the text it gives:

```
#include<stdio.h> ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
```

The space between > and Ì gives me a weird black nul in notepad++

The first line of the file is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

I hope I can find some help here :)

Comment: You are always trying to output 100 bytes (skipping whitespaces). But you should break out of the for loop when the `\0` is encountered in the input as that marks the end of what `fgets` read. Otherwise you are outputting past valid input and hence garbage results.

Comment: extending @kaylum comment, `i < sizeof a` should be `i < sizeof(a) && a[i]`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof a; i++) {` --> `for (size_t i = 0; a[i]; i++) {`

Comment: "weird black nul" is like the `'\0'` character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof a; i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0' && i < sizeof a; i++) {
```

In your case, in the first call of `fgets()` gives array `a` these values: '#', 'i', 'n', 'c', ..., 'o', '.', 'h', '>' and a '\0'. However, the rest of `a` still contains garbages like `Ì`, because `a` is never initialised.

The '\0' is just the "weird black nul" you mentioned. A '\0' is the signal of the end of a C-style string, but it does not stand for the end of a file, so it shouldn't be written to "Disc.c" using `fputc()`

Answer (score -1):

`sizeof a` is the size of the variable `a` in bytes, which is always 100. You want to cap your loop with the length of the string held in `a`, which is `strlen(a)`.

Also, you shouldn't write to file streams character by character. That's not how file I/O is designed to work.

Comment: Writing a character at a time isn't really a problem, since it's being buffered (and the output is being filtered to remove some characters).  There is no advantage to storing the filtered sequence in yet another buffer (as you imply would be better).

Comment: Streams in C actually are designed to be written or read one character at a time. `fgetc` and `fputc` are the primitives and you will find that the other stream functions are implemented by calling one-character primitives  (or you used to, anyway)